# How to extract the fifth or n occurrence with regex?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table like this

```
Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|Address at some where|details 

Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|
```

I want to extract the fifth or n occurrence (use | to determine it) from the table. If the row has lesser than 5 occurrence, I want to return the max occurrence of that row.

Below is my script:

```
with a as (
  select 'Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|Address at some where|details ' from dual test
  union all select 'Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|' from dual test
)
select substr(test,1,(REGEXP_instr(test,'[^|]+',1,5))) from a;
```

Here is my result:

```
Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|A
null
```

My expected outcome:

```
Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|Address at some where|
Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|
```

Is there any way I can do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The question didn't have DBMS tag but table name and regex function name allows to assume that this is Oracle

Comment: You say you want the 5th occurrence of a pipe-delimited string, but your sample expected output shows occurrences 1-5. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match the entire column content (including final pipe) as a group and use match quantifier `{m,n}` to capture no more than 5 groups. Then use `regexp_substr` to extract the match:

```
with a(test) as (
  select 'Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|Address at some where|details ' from dual
  union all select 'Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|' from dual
  union all select 'Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16' from dual
)
select
  test,
  REGEXP_substr(test,'([^|]+\|?){1,5}') as res
from a;
```

| TEST | RES |
| --- | --- |
| Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|Address at some where|details | Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|Address at some where| |
| Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009| | Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009| |
| Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16 | Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1iJ4gHPS)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use such query, it should solve your problem:

```
with a as (
    select 'Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|Address at some where|details ' test from dual
    union all select 'Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|' test from dual
)
select 
  substr(
    test,
    1,
    decode(
      REGEXP_instr(test,'[^|]+', 1, 5, 1),
      0,
      REGEXP_instr(test,'[^|]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(test, '[^|]+'), 1),
      REGEXP_instr(test,'[^|]+', 1, 5, 1)
    )
  )
from a;
```

You can play with query [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/hNDdJaAB).

Answer (score 0):

Or, without regular expressions, using standard `substr + instr` combination (which might perform better on large data sets).

Sample data (borrowed from astentx; thanks!):

```
SQL> with a (test) as (
  2    select 'Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|Address at some where|details ' from dual
  3    union all select 'Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|' from dual
  4    union all select 'Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16' from dual
  5  )
```

Query:

```
  6  select test,
  7    substr(test, 1, case when instr(test, '|', 1, 5) = 0 then length(test)
  8                         else instr(test, '|', 1, 5) - 1
  9                    end
 10          ) as result
 11  from a;

TEST                                                        RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------
Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|Address at some where|details  Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|Address at some where
Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|                               Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16|DY7009|
Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16                                       Jack|Sparrow|17-09-16

SQL>
```